# ompr MILPModel : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, operations-research, ompr

I am familiar with how to use ompr::MIPModel but am trying to learn how to use MILPModel to take advantage of the model build speed.  A simplified version of my model is below.  I have two decision variables, x and y, binary and of equal length.  I have constraints on the sum of all the x decision variables, and the sum of all the y decision variables.  So far so good with MILPModel, I can build the model and solve it fast.

The problem is when I try to use the next constraint.  The LHS of this constraint multiplies the x binary decision variables by a numeric column in a dataframe of the same length, then multiplies that by a matrix where the rows are equal to the length of x.  Similar story in the RHS with the y variable.  I then iterate this constraint 20 times to represent all the columns of the matrix.

I've used constraints similar to this many times using MIPModel, but now when I try this I get an error message, `non-numeric argument to binary operator`.  I assume this has something to do with the `colwise` function, but I am unfamiliar with how to approach this, even after reading up on the ompr github site.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
add_variable(x[i], i=1:10, type='binary') %>%
add_variable(y[i], i=1:10, type='binary') %>%
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i],i=1:10) <= 5) %>%
add_constraint(sum_expr(y[i],i=1:10) <= 3) %>%

#model builds and solves until this point...
add_constraint( 
sum_expr( x[i]* df$numeric_column[i] * matrix_a[i,j],i=1:10) <= 
sum_expr(  2* y[i]* df$numeric_column[i] * df$other_numeric_column[i] * matrix_a[i,j],i=1:10), 
j=1:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  To use matrix algebra in a constraint requires a little bit of acrobatics.  Good luck figuring out how to use matrix algebra in the objective function, should you need to.

Example comparing MIPModel to MILPModel is below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)

rm(list=ls())

numvec1 <- runif(10)
numvec2 <- runif(10)
matrix_a <- matrix(nrow=10,ncol=20,data=runif(10*20))

my_mip_model <- MIPModel() %>%
  
  add_variable(x[i], i=1:10, type='binary') %>%
  add_variable(y[i], i=1:10, type='binary') %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(numvec1[i]*x[i],i=1:10) <= 5) %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(2*y[i],i=1:10) <= 3) %>%
  
  add_constraint( 
    sum_expr( x[i]* numvec1[i] * matrix_a[i,j],i=1:10) <= 
      sum_expr(  2* y[i]* numvec1[i] * numvec2[i] * matrix_a[i,j],i=1:10), 
    j=1:20) %>%
  set_objective( sum_expr(3*x[i]*numvec1[i],i=1:10),sense='max')

my_mip_model_solve <- my_mip_model %>% solve_model(with_ROI(solver='glpk'))



#functionally equivalent using MILPmodel----

my_milp_model <- MILPModel() %>%
  
  add_variable(x[i], i=1:10, type='binary') %>%
  add_variable(y[i], i=1:10, type='binary') %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr( colwise(numvec1[i]) * x[i],i=1:10) <= 5) %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr( colwise(2) * y[i],i=1:10) <= 3)  %>%
  set_objective(sum_expr( colwise(3*numvec1[i]) * x[i],i=1:10),sense='max')

#now to add the matrix constraints, add a loop on the matrix column index j.
#with MIPModel we could just iterate on j in a single constraint, but here it appears
#we need to add the same constraint multiple times, and use the value of j to
#calculate the indices in as.numeric(matrix_a) that we want to use.
for(j in 1:ncol(matrix_a)){
  
  my_milp_model %<>% add_constraint(
    
    sum_expr( x[i]* colwise(numvec1[i] *
      as.numeric(matrix_a)[(i + (nrow(matrix_a)*j -nrow(matrix_a)))]),i=1:10) <= 
        sum_expr(  y[i]* colwise(2* numvec1[i] * numvec2[i] * 
    as.numeric(matrix_a)[(i + (nrow(matrix_a)*j -nrow(matrix_a)))]) ,i=1:10) ) 
    
}

my_milp_model_solve <- my_milp_model %>% solve_model(with_ROI(solver='glpk'))

#objective value and results should be equal...
my_mip_model_solve
my_milp_model_solve
```